# Which Wireless Adapter should I buy?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, pci-express, expansion-cards

The wireless adapter I had was a D-Link DWA 556.

I had this one for a short while, and then it started having problems(dropping connections, speed dips, etc.) So I decided to buy a new one. Here are the ones I have been looking at:

-[N53](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833320113)

and

-[N15](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833320074)

The N53 is Dual Band, which I was interested in because my router is Dual Band, but then I was questioning if I'd actually need it and just use 2.4GHz. The N15 (seems like) the non-dual band equivalent. I was wondering which one you would recommend and if you'd please tell me why, that'd be great. I'm an online gamer, if that helps. Also, if you know of another adapter that would suit me, please link it.

Comment: Welcome to [su]! This isn't really a place to solicit shopping or software recommendations (as noted in the [faq]). You can, however, try asking around in the [chat] to see if someone's available who can offer input there.

Comment: I have already read the FAQ. While it is purchase, I just used that for context, it's not set up as "What Graphics Card would you recommend for...?" which would be wrong. I'm presenting two pieces of hardware and asking which provides more strength. Then I asked if I needed 5GHz connection, because I wasn't sure of the benefits of using it. If you read the FAQ, this is completely valid and accepted.

Comment: Still, the reason that rule exists is because shopping recommendations become quickly outdated, and in this industry faster than most others. Questions and answers on this site should be able to stand up to the test of time (within reasonable definitions), and recommendations, even ones this narrow, become completely invalidated just as soon as the next update is out. I dare say it's already outdated, with [802.11ac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ac) already hitting consumers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the n15, especially if you're primarily worried about online gaming. You're not going to see any performance improvements in-game as your Internet connection is going to be slower than either card's maximum throughput. You might see *some* improvements elsewhere, but honestly you'd probably never notice the difference, except being short $25 dollars.

Here's a little more info on it:
http://compnetworking.about.com/od/wirelessfaqs/f/5ghz-gear.htm